# create and save sql dump to remote

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, unix, ssh

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname > db_dump.sql
```

will create sql dump on local machine.

How to create dump from local server to remote location like

```
mysqldump -u local_username -p local_dbname > ip/remote_machine/folder/db_dump.sql
```

Because my webspace on local machine is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

read documentation about sql dump from local to remote
https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/remote-sql-server-backups-explained

Comment: to use this software you need sql database which allow external access. My database allow access only from localhost/server.